# В консоле браузера заметил ошибку отправки пост данных

Tags: google-chrome, консоль

Я даже не знаю куда отнести этот вопрос. Но я заметил в консоли хрома ошибку отправки пост данных на вот этот адрес,

> https://the-extension.com/stats?hash=ker87w3mwr4zpbhr06uoez5mi&eventCategory=eval&eventAction=run&eventLabel=v20171202

я не пойму что за данные оправляються, на все сайтах со временем в консоле такое есть. Как узнать воопше какой скрипт отправляет эти данные? И что вообще это за сайт такой?

Comment: Очевидно, у вас в браузере стоит какое-то вредоносное расширение, какое — вам виднее

Comment: Каспер по этому адресу ругается, что там распространение вредоносов

Comment: а как узнать какое, если даный пост проявляется по времени рандомно. Прийдеться по 1 отключать и ждать сколько? Есть ли возможность как то узнать какое разширение такое дает?